# how to execute function on ng-repeater running

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have problem with ng-repeater in angular I want to  execute function to do calculation  on run my problem now the function is not execute when I pass the Id https://jsfiddle.net/gkqL3zdp/1/
can someone help me ?

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="category in model.categories"> <span> Category: {{ category.name }} </span>
        <div ng-click="getID(category.Id)">
    </div>
</div>
debugger;
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller('ctrl', ['$scope',

function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        categories: [{
            "Id": 1,
            name: '1'
        }, {
            "Id": 2,
            name: '2'
        },{
            "Id": 3,
            name: '3'
        },{
            "Id": 4,
            name: '4'
        }]

    }
    $scope.getID = function(id){
        id=+2
        console.log(parentId)
        return result;
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-init for that.
On the same div use something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="repeatExpression">
  <div ng-init="getId()"></div>
</diV>
```

Comment: the problem with that will run first categories id ?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code. Now ng-repeat will execute and on every repeat it will initialize inner div with getId()

Answer (score 0):

your clickable divs were 0 height and your parentId and result variables were undefined. I fixed in https://jsfiddle.net/gkqL3zdp/1/

```
$scope.getID = function(id){
    console.log(id)
    return id;
}
```

Comment: what I am asking  how to execute function getID without ng-click ?